# How to adjust the 'c' parameter in the Matplotlib.Axes.scatter method?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to draw a scatterplot with the colormap of my choice.

My code:

```
# Create a scatter plot.
scatter = axes[1][1].scatter(
fourth.VALP, # First value to use.
fourth['TAXP'].map(taxp_convert), # Second value.
s = fourth['WGTP'].map(MinimizeSize), # Size of each point is its WGTP value 
and minimizing the size
c = fourth.MRGP, # Color of each point is its MRGP value.
marker ='o')
```

Result:
[image: Scatter Plot with color bar]

However, I want the color to be like this:

[image: Desired color scheme]

I only know that the `c` parameter in `axes.scatter` is responsible for color, but I don't know how to change it to the desired color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing everything correctly. The `c` parameter is the quantity by which the scatter points are colorized according to a colormap. It may also be used to specify the colors directly (one color per point).

If you want to change the default colormap, you may use the `cmap` argument. E.g.

```
plt.scatter(...., cmap="coolwarm")
```

would give you a plot like the desired one. 
For a complete overview check the [colormaps_reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)